# How to change one array same as another array

Tags: javascript, html

I have two arrays. I want compare modified array with original array and I want to change the modified array same as the original array. position want to be same also

I am expecting following output is, my inputs are I have put in snippet

```
const modified = [
                    {label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},
                    {label: 'cover2', formUid: 211},
                    {label: 'cover3', formUid: 204},
                    {label: 'cover4', formUid: 258},
                    {label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},
                ]
```

but now I am getting like this output, this is not show the **{label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},** this object in 0th index

```
const modified = [
                    {label: 'cover2', formUid: 211},
                    {label: 'cover3', formUid: 204},
                    {label: 'cover4', formUid: 258},
                    {label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},
                 ]
```

```js
    const original = [
               {label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},
               {label: 'cover2', formUid: 211},
               {label: 'cover3', formUid: 204},
               {label: 'cover4', formUid: 258},
               {label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},
            ];
                           
    const modified = [
               {label: 'cover4', formUid: 258},
               {label: 'cover2', formUid: 211},
               {label: 'cover3', formUid: 204},
               {label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},
               {label: 'cover1', formUid: 1045},
            ]
        
function testFunc(original , modified){
 let originalCopyForPosision;
      
 originalCopyForPosision = [...original];
             
 modified.forEach((element,idx) => {
                 
    let targetIndex = originalCopyForPosision.findIndex(e => e.formUid === element.formUid)
                 
     if(idx === targetIndex){
            return
       }else{
                 
            if(targetIndex > 0){
               modified.splice(targetIndex,  1);
               modified.splice(idx,0,element);
            }
                   
         }
        
      })
        
  document.getElementById("originalArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(original);
   document.getElementById("modifiedArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(modified);
        
}testFunc(original,modified)
```

```html
<p id="originalArray"></p>
<p id="modifiedArray"></p>
```

Comment: If you dont care about the reference of the original array you can just create a new array\assign the modified to the original.

If you do care about that, cant you just remove all the elements and copy the modified into the original?

Why do you need the compare\ what are you actually comparing?

Comment: @connexo I have fix the intends problem

Comment: @Yftach Actually I want to compare my modified array with original array and I want to make my modified array same as original array both array can be duplicate objects . In my code when I compare duplicate objects are not finding corectly

Comment: @KevinMac746 im asking specifically, why are you trying to compare them? If you just want a copy of the original array you can just copy it. Why is the compare part necessary?

Comment: @Yftach this is one part of my work. there are lot of parts have in back. So according to that works I cant copy an past. If I say simply. I have two arrays firstly one is original second is modified. modified array is making from original array So there can be additional objects more than original array. I have compare both and create a MACRO somthing like "COVER1 is DELETED FROM 1" like this all process are created in one place.

Comment: finally I get a new array there include all original array objects and newly added objects and i have to remove some object(there have some another logic to describe), So this is my final step. now my modified array is mixed one, So I want to compare it with original one and fix the positioning all these.

Comment: Are the modifications just delete\add\move or can the objects themeselves be modified. How are you tracking object equality? just by formUid or a combo of formUid and label?

Comment: previous processes I have set flag for counted object . So it avoid getting wrong duplicate objects, But here I cant do that

Comment: @KevinMac746, based on the comment, I predict you **must** you the orginal code, but only solve the problem. Is it correct?

Comment: sorry I didnt get that

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion

```js
    const original = [
  { label: "cover1", formUid: 1045 },
  { label: "cover2", formUid: 211 },
  { label: "cover3", formUid: 204 },
  { label: "cover4", formUid: 258 },
  { label: "cover1", formUid: 1045 },
];

const modified = [
  { label: "cover2", formUid: 211 },
  { label: "cover1", formUid: 204 },
  { label: "cover4", formUid: 258 },
  { label: "cover3", formUid: 1045 },
  { label: "cover1", formUid: 1045 },
];

function test() {
  let modifiedCopy = modified.slice();
  original.forEach((value, i) => {
    if (
      value.formUid !== modifiedCopy[i].formUid
    ) {
      modifiedCopy[i] = original[i];
    }
  });
  console.log(modified, "\n\n", original, modifiedCopy);
}

test();
```

Comment: This is actually good. This is destroy the modified array right? is that correct

Comment: As well as I can see this give the original array object to modified array object. But I am expecting some swapping part in here. that mean without getting data from original array have any way to do modification only in modified array

Comment: As well as I always try to track the index of the array because labels can be change anyTime

Comment: That means you want to compare `formUid` of labels with with original?

Comment: I want to compare INDEX of the object and FORMUID with the original. Dont destroy any any arrays make a copy of them then arrays will save, I have do in my code that

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: yes. I will have some suggestions. And am trying in this time also. I we have a way to move array object by index. I think this problem will be solvedd

Comment: If my answer is correct, please accept the answer. If not, state your question more clearly